# Problem with Broadcom BCM4312 on Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I'm new in Ubuntu and I have a problem with my Wireless card Broadcom BCM 4312...

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop on my netbook with USB, because i haven't got CD/DVD-ROM....Installation looks fine, Ubuntu works fine, too, but I cant connect to the internet by Wi-Fi. I don't know, what should I do with it..:( ... BTW: I can connect to Internet via LAN, but at my home I can't connect by LAN, because we have Internet developer, which banned connecting from other IP....but that's not problem...

Can anyone help me, please? :)

...and I connect there some print screens of PCI list, iwconfig and Installing bcmwl-kernel-source (this language is Slovakian, but it says, that you must insert install CD into media/cdrom, but I haven't got CD-ROM -_-...

[image]

Thank you in advance for every answer :)

```
domosino@domosinoPC:~$ lspci -nn -d : | grep 14e4
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1713] (rev 02)
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
```

I tried `sudo apt-get update` and Broadcom driver install in setting, but it no work :/...

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of the wireless device from the terminal command: lspci -nn -d 14e4: Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WiFi disconnects for few seconds and resume](http://askubuntu.com/questions/730908/wifi-disconnects-for-few-seconds-and-resume)

Answer (score 0):

Use either a wired or bluetooth tethered connection to get wifi temporarily up and running, then run:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Then open 'Software and Updates'  and select the proprietary Broadcom driver.